# Cannot print non-english characters in Aptana

Tags: python, utf-8, pydev, aptana, non-ascii-characters

I'm new to both Aptana and Python.

Is there a way to print non-english characters? like **ñ é ψ ü** etc.

Now, when I try to: print "ñ" for example, I get a:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file D:\Users\User1\Documents\Aptana Studio 3 Workspace\Testing\stuff.py on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I do have the encoding se to utf-8 in:
Window > Preferences > General > Workspace > Text encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

on the top of your python file

Comment: It works! I see the specification here: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/

Thanks!